# How can I automatically go to the last selected child state when I view only the parent state with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have the following set up:

```
   var admin = {
        name: 'admin',
        url: '/admin',
        views: {
            'menu': {
                templateUrl: '/Content/app/admin/partials/menu.html',
            },
            'content': {
                templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                    var content = localStorage.getItem('ls.adminPage');
                    if (content != null && content != "") {
                        return '/Content/app/admin/partials/' + content + '.html';
                    }  else {
                        return '/Content/app/common/partials/empty.html';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var adminContent = {
        name: 'admin.content',
        parent: 'admin',
        url: '/:content',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                    localStorage.setItem('ls.adminPage', stateParams.content);
                    return '/Content/app/admin/partials/' + stateParams.content + '.html';
                },
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens is that when a user has previously been to the `/admin/xxx` page then the next time `/admin` is selected it will again return the `/admin/xxx` page.

However visually this is a mess as the browser URL shows as `/admin` and the state is not set correctly.

Is there some way I can store away a child state and then have it so that when the user browses to the parent that it will transition to the last known child state and have that URL show in the browswer ?

Comment: Have you looked at onEnter functions for ui-router? Just wondering is you could save the last visted admin child state name in local storage like you do the template, and if there is one do a $state.go('last-child-state')?

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
myapp.config(function($urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.when('/admin', function() {
    var content = localStorage.getItem('ls.adminpage');
    if ( content != null && content != "" ) {
      return "/admin/" + content;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/oEXZpO

Edit: Revisiting this answer after two months I realize that it is a little short (to say the least) on explanation: So this will actually "redirect" the request to the last selected admin page so that it will show up in the URL. I have updated the Plunkr and added a function to show the current document URL. So one can see that after clicking on /admin/ the URL will actually be /admin/12345 if this was the admin sub page visited before.